# How to customize the delay between event notifications in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory has a neat feature of sending emails for changed repositories but I wasn't able to find a place where I can configure how much time to wait before sending such notification.

As a result it does send lots of incremental emails if you are trying to upload a lot of data.

I suspect that it does have a place where this happens because the notifications are send in batches, not one per uploaded artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay between event notification email is 60 seconds.
Currently, there is no easy way of changing this value.
It could be a nice feature request.